# Google Apps Script - Custom Menu Available to Spreadsheet Editors

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sharing a Google spreadsheet with many people (both editors and viewers).  I have a custom menu that is an installable trigger [onMyOpen()] that has useful functions for the user.  I have two questions:

1) The spreadsheet editors will be able to use the menu functions, right?  And the spreadsheet viewers will NOT be able to use the menu functions?

2) For the spreadsheet editors to access the menu (and run the scripts), do they need to do anything first?  For example, do they need to authorize the script?  Or will it ask them to "accept" when they try to run the function from the menu the first time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answers : (1) yes (viewers will see the custom menu but it will be grayed out) and (2) yes it will run without any other user action and yes they will be prompted for authorization when executing one of the functions.

Why wouldn't you simply try this yourself ? You can test it yourself with another mail account, if you don't have one just create it, it will be very useful if you're going to use Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did, but shared it with my other account a while ago and forgot what happened the first time I tried to run the function.  I guess I could have re-shared it (or just created another account)!

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry I didn't recognize you at first, I didn't pay attention to the name... thx for accepting.

Comment: Just curious why are you using a custom myonopen when the regular onOpen will work too?